# How to submit a form after event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a html form like this. Below is my html code and jQuery code.My intention is when user selects "Delete" option and click on "Apply", I want to first confirm user's decision and if user clicks "ok", the form will be submitted. However, I am kind of lost now. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

HTML:

```
  <div>
    <select id="option_selection">
        <option value="">Select Options</option>
        <option value="approve">Approve</option>
        <option value="unapprove">Unapprove</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
    </select>
</div>

    <div>
        <input id="apply" type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply">
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $("#apply").on('click',function(event){
    if($('#option_selection').val() == "delete"){
        event.preventDefault();
        var answer=confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");

        if(answer){
            $("#option_selection").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't prevent the default action if the user presses "yes".

Comment: The HTML you've posted is inside a `<form>` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is
**Change**

```
   event.preventDefault();
   var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
   if (answer) {
       $("#option_selection").submit();
   }
```

**To**

```
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    if (!answer) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. You need to keep everything simplest :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, is better doing it through Ajax. I mean that calling `event.preventDefault()` and after `$("#form").submit` are loop statements.  [How to make an Ajax call through JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)